# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-icons/ai'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-icons

I am learning ReactJS. But now I got a problem. I used this code

```
import { AiOutlineShoppingCart } from "react-icons/ai"
```

But it is showing this error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-icons/ai'
```

I am using sanity to build an eCommerce website cms. I tried to install react-icons with this code

```
yarn add react-icons
```

and I have checked the packages .jeson file and react-icons are present in dependencies. Can anyone please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Some extra info:

- I have also use react-icons instead of react-icons/ai but same error
- I have used npm install to install react-icons. Nothing helps

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should be aware that not all icons are available. I sometime try to import some icons and I get error.

Secondly, make sure you copy the code from the website to make sure you didnot misspell the name

Futhermore, you can delete your node_module and remove react-icons from package.json file, then do `yarn add react-icons` and do yarn to install all your packages again

Lastly, you're to import from the library that owns the icon, i.e. if you're importing from `AiFillAudio`, you're to import it from `react-icons/ai`. eg.
`import { AiFillAudio } from react-icons/ai`.

I hope this help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have found the way. But I know about "node_module" from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling with `npm install react-icons --save` command

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My react-icons are installed in sanity the folder. So when I was importing AiOutlineShoppingCart from react-icons, my program was looking for react-icons inside node_module of my main file. But it is stored node_module of sanity. So I have to **declare the whole path**.

**Working code is**

```
import { AiOutlineShoppingCart } from "../sanity/node_modules/react-icons/ai"
```

Here, "sanity" means sanity folder name.

Thanks, everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes occurs when you install dependencies in the wrong directory.

let's say you run  `npm i package-x` outside your project directory

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was trying to use a named export from a CommonJS module. Try something like this instead, which worked for me:

```js
import ai from "react-icons/ai"
const { AiOutlineShoppingCart } = ai
```